# Firebase Document Amount with Function via Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();    
  }

String? currentuseruid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
int? notificationamountData;

  getData() async {
    try {
      var userSnap = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('notifications')
          .doc(currentuseruid)
          .collection('user-notifications')
          .snapshots();
      notificationamountData = await userSnap.length;
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(
        context,
        e.toString(),
      );
    }
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Text(notificationamountData.toString()),

}
```

I am trying to get the amount of notifications in a firebase collection. Even though I have 1 notification, I am getting null within the "notificationamountData.toString()". What should I change so that I get the correct amount of notifications?

Comment: You should try to await the FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notifications').doc(currentuseruid).collection('user-notifications').snapshots(); instead of the userSnap.length;.

Also try checking the value of  notificationamountData  before running the toString() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get the amount of notifications in a Firestore
> collection. ... `userSnap.length`

I understand that you want to count how many documents you have in the `notifications` collection.

You can indeed query the entire collection and use the [`size`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/size.html) property of the `QuerySnapshot` but this will **cost one read for each document in the collection**.

Recently, Firebase has issued the [`count()` aggregation query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) which "allows you to determine the number of documents in a collection or query" and which cost much less. You are actually charged "one document read for each batch of up to 1000 index entries matched by the query" as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#aggregation_queries).

In Dart it was added in `cloud_firestore` version 4.0.0. You need to use the `count` property of an [`AggregateQuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/AggregateQuerySnapshot-class.html) as follows:

```
AggregateQuerySnapshot aqs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notifications').count().get();

int notificationamountData = aqs.count;
```

Comment: Super! thank you so much Renaud. This solves my problem. Also great to know about the cost involvement...

Comment: Done!  Happy to!